# Updated to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. screen resolution stuck at 640x480 on Dell Dimension C521

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, resolution

I just updated Ubuntu to 14.04 from 12.04 and I have this display issue where the monitor is stuck at 640x480 - it won't give me any other option choices.

I used The `lspci | grep VGA` and this is my result:

```
00:05.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation C51 [GeForce 6150 LE] (rev a2)
```

Can anyone could give me any assistance to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have the restricted driver installed for your system. Go to settings and click on Restricted drivers and select one of the options for your Nvidia card. I have a similar card and found the recommended and tested driver (nvidia-331 I belive) worked well.

Comment: Thank you Mordoc for your input. I resolve the problem by opening up "Ubuntu Software Center" Then on the tabs menu I clicked "Edit >>Software Sources" then on the tabs I went to additional drivers. and There were several options which I tried and YESS one of the options worked.